# Is there a way to move (scroll) selected line in Xcode to the top?

Tags: xcode, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a keyboard shortcut to scroll my current window within Xcode to the top of the page. Similar to Emacs, I know that `^L` will bring current selected line to the center. However, in Emacs, if I press it again, it will bring that line to the top.

I am looking for similar behavior in Xcode, I have searched and tried multiple custom Key Bindings, but non seem to have what I am looking for.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a semi-solution that works for scrolling up a number of lines modifying the `IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist` file in the Xcode Resources directory. If you know how many lines half of your screen is, you could use this with `^ L` and use to keyboard shortcuts to accomplish what I am looking for.

I have added the following to my file and created to custom keybindings to scroll up 6 lines up or down.

```
<key>Customized</key>
<dict>
    <key>Scroll Up 6 Lines</key>
    <string>scrollLineUp:, scrollLineUp:, scrollLineUp:, scrollLineUp:, scrollLineUp:, scrollLineUp:</string>
    <key>Scroll Down 6 Lines</key>
    <string>scrollLineDown:, scrollLineDown:, scrollLineDown:, scrollLineDown:, scrollLineDown:, scrollLineDown:</string>
</dict>
```

The file can be found at */Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Resources/IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist* and you can add it before the last `</dict>` tag.

Another option would be to scroll down on the page beyond the selected line and then press one of the arrow keys to bring it to the top.